# Mysql querying multiple options

Tags: mysql, select

I have a query such as:

```
SELECT bp.*, b.company 
FROM `DBPREFIXwindows_brands_products` bp 
LEFT JOIN `DBPREFIXwindows_brands` b ON bp.brand_id = b.id 
JOIN Windows_last_submissions ls
WHERE bp.width = ROUND(ls.width)
AND bp.height = ROUND(ls.height) 
AND bp.material = ls.chosenmaterial
AND bp.type = ls.type
AND IF 
(ls.minimumbid != 'NULL',bp.cost BETWEEN (ls.minimumbid AND ls.maximumbid),bp.cost <= ls.maximumbid)
```

the field 'chosenmaterial' comes from a select box which can hold multiple options.  My question is, within this query - how do I make the WHERE clause work so that if a person chooses more than 1 option, (which obviously separate into row with commas) how can I query anything which includes any and all of those options??

Comment: In addition..I'm having trouble with single options too because the option appears as 'option,' with the comma at the end whether there is one options or more than one.  Obviously this interferes with the query..Is there any "if any of these options are in the 'bp.material' row", query all of the above?

Comment: chooses more than 1 option, (which obviously separate into row with commas) - obvious? Not to me. Please explain

Comment: I'm sorry.  The materials row is populated from a select box with different values (5 in total).  The datatype as of now is "Char" (I was using "varchar" earlier with the same results).  If the user chooses one option - it displays in the database as "vinyl," with the comma after it...and the same it they choose, say, "vinyl,wood".  As I'm typing this I'm wondering if it's coming from the form I'm using...  Or possible I could just remove the "," characters in my query??

Comment: Sorry, why does it have a comma? Ah, yes - sounds like an issue with the form. Not sure really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `IN` operator for that field. If you can build a list of chosen materials that matches a pattern like:

```
(material1, material2, material3)
```

You can make your where clause something like this:

```
WHERE bp.material IN (material1, material2, material3)
```

which will pull any rows that have one of those three materials. In a way, it's just a simplified version of having multiple `OR` statements:

```
WHERE material = material1 OR material = material2 OR material = material3
```

Comment: @CaseyStack glad I could help! If this is the solution you use feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers will know what solved your problem.